# SnappyData SQL PUT INTO not updating values

Tags: sql, snappydata

Hi I am using SnappyData and trying to update `Table_A` with rows from `Table_B`:

```
Table_A(key1, key2, val, primary key(key1, key2)) -- cumulative results
Table_B(key1, key2, val, primary key(key1, key2)) -- new rows - updates
```

Since the `Table_B` would contain (key1, key2) values that already exist in `Table_A`, and should replace those in `Table_A`. So I am using the "[PUT INTO](http://gemfirexd.docs.pivotal.io/1.3.1/userguide/reference/language_ref/put-into.html)" instead of "INSERT INTO" statements to update the cumulative results stored in `Table_A`

And my PUT INTO statement looks like this:

```
PUT INTO Table_A
SELECT * from Table_B
```

But the rows in `Table_B` does not show up in `Table_A`.

However if I insert values directly:

```
PUT INTO Table_A
VALUES (1, 1, 1)
```

the row (1, 1, 1) does show up in `Table_A`. And if I use INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A
SELECT * from Table_B
```

The rows from `Table_B` show up in `Table_A`, until there is a dup key error and my program exits.

I tried single column primary key (i.e. key1) and still no luck.

So what am I doing wrong here? Or is the "PUT INTO" not working or is there a delay in "PUT INTO" statements?

UPDATE:

I was using SnappyData local mode, and I just tried cluster mode and encountered some error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402885/snappydata-snappy-sql-put-into-cause-errorspark-sql-execution-id-is-already-set) (strange it does not throw the error in local mode, instead it's just not working silently.)

Comment: Will get this answered for you ASAP

Comment: Thanks for the comment, please see my updated message and the error I encountered here in cluster mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402885/snappydata-snappy-sql-put-into-cause-errorspark-sql-execution-id-is-already-set

Comment: You just need to provide table_a schema in the put into statement - So it should be : snappy> put into table_a (key1, val) select * from table_b;

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now! It would be great if you post your answer and i'll upvote yours :) 
Also it would be great if you guys can update the document:
http://rowstore.docs.snappydata.io/docs/reference/language_ref/put-into.html
it's kind of frustrating following the document while it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to provide table_a schema in the put into statement - So it should be : snappy> put into table_a (key1, val) select * from table_b;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we have added a doc ticket to track this and docs should be updated accordingly. Thanks.